# Jenkinsのサービスが高負荷で停止した場合のログ

Tags: jenkins

はじめまして。
自社でJenkinsを使用しています。
恐れ入りますが、わたし自身は正直Jenkinsは詳しくありません。

先日社内で脆弱性診断のためにポートスキャンをかけました。
するとJenkinsの管理者から「ポートスキャンのせいで対象サーバに負荷がかかり
Jenkinsが止まって、ジョブが実行されなかった」とクレームがありました。

サーバはダウンしてないが、そんなことあるのか？と思い、該当サーバの
Jenkinsやsecurity、accessログ等を確認しましたが、それらしきログはないように見えました。

Jenkinsのサービスが高負荷等で停止した場合「警告」ログ等は残らないのでしょうか？
もし、ログが残るのであればどのようなログが出力されるのかご教示お願い致します。

Comment: Jenkinsのサーバが高負荷で止まったのでしょうか？それとも該当のサーバが高負荷になりJenkinsのジョブ（該当サーバで行う処理）が止まったのでしょうか？そのへんはJenkins管理者からヒアリングすることはできますか？

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。 該当サーバのmessages_logをよく確認すると、負荷がかかりすぎたために、メモリが99％になり、Linuxの仕様で動いているプロセスをkillしました。 そのときにkillされたのがjavaだったためにJenkinsのジョブが止まってしまったようです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「止まった」という表現がダウン状態なのかハング状態なのか、はたまた別の状態なのかで変わってくると思いますが、Jenkinsのログは 起動パラメータで指定されるので起動スクリプトを確認してください。

私の手元のCentos環境では `/etc/init.d/jenkins` が起動スクリプトでその中で `--logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log` がパラメータに指定されています。

JenkinsはJavaのプログラムなので、何かしらのでエラーがあれば スタックトレースが出力されていると思います。スタックトレース以外にも WarningやErrorメッセージも出力されると思いますので ポートスキャンを行った時間帯のメッセージを確認してみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
該当サーバのmessages_logをよく確認すると、負荷がかかりすぎたために、メモリが99％になり、Linuxの仕様で動いているプロセスをkillしました。
そのときにkillされたのがjavaだったためにJenkinsのジョブが止まってしまったようです。